# Alternative of intersects ?# operator in postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, java, query

Is there any way to find if a `path` is intersecting with a `box` in postgres without using `?#` or using an alternative?

I have this query below and hibernate's `EntityManager` is throwing an exception related to questionmark (?)

```
SELECT p.id, p.constraint_id, p.distance, p.height, p.coordinates, p.gtype, p.name 
FROM geometry p 
WHERE p.gtype='PolylineVolume' 
AND path(polygon(box(point(15.740013406952562 - (180/pi()) * (p.distance/(6378137*cos(pi()*15.740013406952562/180))),46.97849625047054 - (180/pi()) * (p.distance/6378137)),point(16.007686681509206 + (180/pi()) * (p.distance/(6378137*cos(pi()*16.007686681509206/180))),47.07276572929793 + (180/pi()) * (p.distance/6378137))))) ?# popen(p.coordinates)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using PostGIS functions/operators for whatever it is you're try to do? (These computations look like a reprojection that is likely to be already implemented.)

Comment: @CL. Because this feature is disabled due to performance overhead

Answer (score 1):

The [PostgreSQL JDBC documenation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/statement.html) says:

> In JDBC, the question mark (`?`) is the placeholder for the positional parameters of a `PreparedStatement`. There are, however, a number of PostgreSQL operators that contain a question mark. To keep such question marks in a SQL statement from being interpreted as positional parameters, use two question marks (`??`) as escape sequence.

Comment: so I must replace the `?#` with `???#` ?

Comment: I tried it but now JDBC demands 3 parameters as the 3 questionmarks

Comment: A single question mark is escaped as `??`. Anyway, which JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: org.postgresql.Driver I have tried it with `??#` and `???#` but the problem exists

Comment: Which version? This escaping is supported since version 9.4.1206, release in 2015.